# HTTPS and sub-domain forward

Tags: google-domains

In google domains I have a sub-domain forward

thedomain.com -> https://www.thedomain.com

It works well when someone types "thedomain.com" or "http://thedomain.com"  -- however, it will NOT WORK for https://thedomain.com.

Is there a way around it? What can I do? the web app behind this domain is on Heroku.

Comment: Your particular stack makes this exceedingly difficult.

Comment: Difficult? or impossible?

Comment: Not impossible. You'd have to host a little server with a fixed IP and the SSL cert to do the non-www to www redirection, or find a redirection service that handles SSL (I've never heard of one, but maybe one exists).